# How to save keras models without tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Tensorflow is very heavy library , is there any way to save and load keras modeles(.h5) without using Tensorflow lib?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score -1):

keras framework is built upon tensorflow. If you want to use keras you will have to install tensorflow library.